# Obtaining first and last row headers for multiple instances of consecutive data in a list- Excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, extract

I have a year calendar in Excel along the lines of the following:

-- Tom -- Dick -- Harry

1 -- x -----------------

2 -- x -----------------

3 -- x -----------------

4 --------x-----------

5 --------x-----------

6 --------x-----------

7 x------------------x

8 x------------------x

9 x------------------x

My data consists of blank cells followed by groups of continuous entries.

I would like to extract and show the first and last dates associated with each grouping of entries. So ideally the output of the function would read:

1. Tom:  1 to 3 & 7 to 9
2. Dick:  5 to 8
3. Harry:  9 to 12

or something to that effect!

Solutions involving VBA or native excel functions would be very much appreciated.

Thank-you all for your time!

Comment: Ah! Apologies, I thought that the site wasn't letting me upload a screenshot of my excel file, hence the (admittedly rather rubbish) attempt at replicating by - and x's above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data:

[image: image1]

Macro:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim mystring As String

For j = 2 To 4 'columns
    For i = 2 To 13 'rows
        If Cells(i, j).Value = "x" Then
            For k = i + 1 To 13 + 1
                If Not Cells(k, j).Value = "x" Then
                    If mystring = "" Then
                        mystring = Cells(1, j).Value & " " & i - 1 & " to " & k - 2
                        i = k - 1
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        mystring = mystring & " & " & Cells(1, j).Value & " " & i - 1 & " to " & k - 2
                        i = k - 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & j - 1).Value = mystring
    mystring = ""
Next j

End Sub
```

Immediate window:

[image: IMW]

Comment: Mate, thank you so much for responding so fast. I am extremely new to VBA (as in, just today). I follow the majority of the logic however when I try to run this I do not receive the desired output. Clearly I have missed something. Thank you once again

Comment: @Dan What's showing up in the immediate window? Are you using the same data as the example above? If you have more data you need to modify the amount of rows/columns that it scans over, the numbers above are based on the *static* example that you gave.

Comment: Ah, I can now see what is happening. Thank you very much once again mate, massively appreciated. Again, clearly, I am a total novice with all this. How would you alter the script to make it output to a cell or MsgBox?

Comment: @Dan I've updated it to print the lines to cells on Sheet2, change as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this `Function()`:

```
Function ExtractFirstAndLast(colIndex As Long)
    Dim area As Range

    With Range(Cells(1, colIndex), Cells(Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then
            ExtractFirstAndLast = .Cells(1, 1) & ":"
            For Each area In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
                ExtractFirstAndLast = ExtractFirstAndLast & " " & Cells(area.Rows(1).row, 1) & " to " & Cells(area.Rows(area.Rows.Count).row, 1) & " &"
            Next
            ExtractFirstAndLast = Left(ExtractFirstAndLast, Len(ExtractFirstAndLast) - 2)
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Function
```

to be called by your "main" Sub as:

```
Sub main()
    MsgBox ExtractFirstAndLast(4) ' this would return "Harry: 7 to 9"
    MsgBox ExtractFirstAndLast(2) ' this would return "Tom: 1 to 3 & 7 to 9
End Sub
```

Comment: Mate, thank you for taking the time to reply to this. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer solved your question then you may consider marking it as accepted. thank you